# Database operation not working in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have precreated a database and put in folder assets.

I created a class `DatabaseHelper` and within that class I created a method `checkDataBase` which opens database and if the operation is successful it will return 1 else 0.

Then I'm calling `checkDataBase` method from my main activity.
if it returns true I just change the text of one of the text fields.

But every time I run my code to call `checkDataBase` method my app crashes.

Following is my code:

```
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

 public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

 public static String DB_Path ="/data/data/com.myapp/app/src/databases";
 private SQLiteDatabase mydatabase;
 private static String DB_NAME = "mydb.sqlite";
 private final Context myContext;

 public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {

     super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
     this.myContext = context;
 }
 public boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        String myPath = DB_Path + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){
        //database does't exist yet.
    }



    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}

 //code to call from main activity
 DatabaseHelper d;
 if(d.checkDataBase())
    {
        txtQue.setText("true");
    }
```

Comment: you have set DB_Path for your PC

Comment: Can you share you logcat please?

Comment: Post Logcat output. Second, you have set absolute path in DB_PATH variable, which is actually referring physical location of your hard-drive, it should be relative to your application path!

Comment: place the db file in assets folder and copy to the device db path and then use it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely in how you build your connection string, the parameter to `openDatabase`.

```
public static String DB_Path ="/data/data/com.myapp/app/src/databases";
private static String DB_NAME = "mydb.sqlite";
...

String myPath = DB_Path + DB_NAME; 
/* myPath here is now "/data/data/.../databasesmydb.sqlite", probably not
   the inteded path */
```

Try this instead:

```
String myPath = DB_Path + "/" + DB_NAME;
```

See if that works.